# How to treat request messages without Transfer-Encoding nor Content-Length headers?

Tags: http, server, request, header, content-length

I am implementing a web server and I was wondering how to treat request messages with a message body but without `Transfer-Encoding` nor `Content-Length` headers (assuming the request method is not HEAD nor CONNECT of course).

According to [RFC 7230, § 3.3.3.  Message Body Length](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.3.3):

> The length of a message body is determined by one of the following (in order of precedence):
>
> […]
>
> 6. If this is a request message and none of the above are true, then the message body length is zero (no message body is present).

Am I in that case, and consequently should I consider the message body length is zero (even though it is not zero in reality)?

Comment: In that case, looks like the message body should be discarded, according to the RFC.

Comment: @shaochuancs Okay, so at least we both have the same understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spec *defines* it. If there is no content-length nor chunked encoding, whatever follows the header section is the next request (possibly malformed).